# Unexpected '?' in LaTex reference

Tags: latex, bibtex, bibliography

Recently, I met a problem in LaTex paper writing. I want to link a website in my reference while '**?**' appeared in my context even if I have compiled the .tex file for many times.

Here is my .bib file,

```
@misc{Jira,
 title = {Jira bug tracking system},
 howpublished = {\url{http://issues.apache.org/jira/}},
}

@misc{Bugzilla,
 title = {Bugzilla bug tracking system},
 howpublished = {\url{https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/}},
}
```

and then I refer this website in my .tex file,

```
\cite{Jira} 
\cite{Bugzilla}
```

but the generated pdf looked liked this `[Jir(???)]` and `[Bug(???)]`, It's strange that other references are all showed correctly while these website references are showed '**?**'. That's the problem I really cannot figure out, who can help me and thanks a lot :)

Comment: What do you mean by "I have compiled the .tex file for many times"? Did you only run `pdflatex` or did you also run `biblatex` or similar? See [Why won't LaTeX generate any output?](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Why_won.27t_LaTeX_generate_any_output.3F).

Comment: Yeah, I know your mean. I use the latex compiler `TeXstudio` and also compile both `pdflatex` and `biblatex` in order. BUT other book or papaer references are all showed correctly while above website references are all showed **?** :(

Comment: If you use an alphabetic style for your bibliography you might need to set an author. Alternatively you could change to a numeric style or set the `label` of the bibliography entries manually (at least I think it was `label`).

Comment: I try to add author or year to complete, but it also show '**?**'. What's more, editor request me to use alphabetic style :( Oh no ... Crazy.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the answer of Tiuri from STACKEXCHANGE TEX community [[Tiuri's answer]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385323/unexpected-in-latex-reference?noredirect=1#comment954386_385323). I posed several suggestions about my question.

1. My citation format is wrong. I use `@misc` label to record website references, but I forget to add ***year*** and ***author*** fileds in `@misc`, i.e., the complete citation should be,

   ```
   @misc{Jira,
     author = "{Jira}",
     title = {{Jira bug tracking system}},
     howpublished = {\url{http://issues.apache.org/jira/}},
     year = 2017,
   }
   ```
2. My citation usage is wrong. When you directly want to cite the whole website
   , such as ***Jira***, ***Bugzilla***, ***Mozilla***, you should use `\footnote{}` label to replace `\cite{}` label. Hence, for this example, I should modify my citation to,

   ```
   \footnote{Jira, \url{http://issues.apache.org/jira/}}
   ```